# View .pdf file using Google Doc Viewer + Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, google-document-viewer

In my application, I want to view my `.pdf` file using Google Doc Viewer.

I am using [Paperclip gem](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip) to upload file. In below code,

`asset.uploaded_file.path` will give `file:///home/rick/rick/Projects/practice/sharebox/assets/137/Screenshot_from_2014-02-26_18_46_52.png`

In my asset model,

```
has_attached_file :uploaded_file,
:url => "/assets/get/:id",
:path => "#{Rails.root}/assets/:id/:basename.:extension"
```

In my `index.html` file

```
@assets.each do |asset|
  <iframe src="https://docs.google.com/viewer?url=http://localhost:3000/<%= asset.uploaded_file.path %>&embedded=true" width="100%" height="800" >
    <p>Your browser does not support iframes.</p>
  </iframe>
end
```

Using this above code i always get this error 'Apologies.
There is no preview available.'

If i will copy this `file:///home/rick/rick/Projects/practice/sharebox/assets/137/Screenshot_from_2014-02-26_18_46_52.png` and paste in new tab in browser, it will show image.

My assets is stored in the folder that is `app_name/assets/id_name/filename`.

So How i should pass path of my file to view using Google Viewer?

Thanks.